# Identifying a cluster of low transit speeds in GPS tracking data

Tags: r, gps

I'm working with a GPS tracking dataset, and I've been playing around with filtering the dataset based on speed and time of day. The species I am working with becomes inactive around dusk, during which it rests on the ocean's surface, but then resumes activity once night has fallen. For each animal in the dataset, I would like to remove all data points after it initially becomes inactive around dusk (21:30). But because each animal becomes inactive at different times, I cannot simply filter out all the data points occurring after 21:30.

My data looks like this...

```
AnimalID  Latitude  Longitude  Speed  Date  
99B       50.86190  -129.0875  5.6    2015-05-14 21:26:00 
99B       50.86170  -129.0875  0.6    2015-05-14 21:32:00
99B       50.86150  -129.0810  0.5    2015-05-14 21:33:00
99B       50.86140  -129.0800  0.3    2015-05-14 21:40:00
99C.......
```

Essentially, I want to find a cluster of GPS positions (say, a minimum of 5), occurring after 21:30:00, that all have speeds of <0.8. I then want to delete all points after this point (including the identified cluster).

Does anyone know a way of identifying clusters of points in R? Or is this type of filtering WAY to complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table`, you can use a rolling forward/backwards max to find the max of the next five or previous five entries by animal ID. Then, filter out any that don't meet the criteria. For example:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(40)
DT <- data.table(Speed = runif(1:1000), AnimalID = rep(c("A","B"), each = 500))

DT[ , FSpeed := Reduce(pmax,shift(Speed,0:4, type = "lead", fill = 1)), by = .(AnimalID)] #0 + 4 forward
DT[ , BSpeed := Reduce(pmax,shift(Speed,0:4, type = "lag", fill = 1)), by = .(AnimalID)] #0 + 4 backwards

DT[FSpeed < 0.5 | BSpeed < 0.5] #min speed

          Speed AnimalID    FSpeed    BSpeed
 1: 0.220509197        A 0.4926640 0.8897597
 2: 0.225883211        A 0.4926640 0.8897597
 3: 0.264809801        A 0.4926640 0.6648507
 4: 0.184270587        A 0.4926640 0.6589303
 5: 0.492664002        A 0.4926640 0.4926640
 6: 0.472144689        A 0.4721447 0.4926640
 7: 0.254635219        A 0.7409803 0.4926640
 8: 0.281538568        A 0.7409803 0.4926640
 9: 0.304875597        A 0.7409803 0.4926640
10: 0.059605991        A 0.7409803 0.4721447
11: 0.132069268        A 0.2569604 0.9224052
12: 0.256960449        A 0.2569604 0.9224052
13: 0.005059727        A 0.8543111 0.2569604
14: 0.191478376        A 0.8543111 0.2569604
15: 0.170969244        A 0.4398143 0.7927442
16: 0.059577719        A 0.4398143 0.7927442
17: 0.439814267        A 0.4398143 0.7927442
18: 0.307714603        A 0.9912536 0.4398143
19: 0.075750773        A 0.9912536 0.4398143
20: 0.100589403        A 0.9912536 0.4398143
21: 0.032957748        A 0.4068012 0.7019594
22: 0.080091554        A 0.4068012 0.7019594
23: 0.406801193        A 0.9761119 0.4068012
24: 0.057445020        A 0.9761119 0.4068012
25: 0.308382143        A 0.4516870 0.9435490
26: 0.451686996        A 0.4516870 0.9248595
27: 0.221964923        A 0.4356419 0.9248595
28: 0.435641917        A 0.5363373 0.4516870
29: 0.237658906        A 0.5363373 0.4516870
30: 0.324597512        A 0.9710011 0.4356419
31: 0.357198893        B 0.4869905 0.9226573
32: 0.486990475        B 0.4869905 0.9226573
33: 0.115922994        B 0.4051843 0.9226573
34: 0.010581766        B 0.9338841 0.4869905
35: 0.003976893        B 0.9338841 0.4869905
36: 0.405184342        B 0.9338841 0.4051843
37: 0.412468699        B 0.4942280 0.9113595
38: 0.402063509        B 0.4942280 0.9113595
39: 0.494228013        B 0.8254665 0.4942280
40: 0.123264949        B 0.8254665 0.4942280
41: 0.251132449        B 0.4960371 0.9475821
42: 0.496037128        B 0.8845043 0.4960371
43: 0.250853014        B 0.3561290 0.9858652
44: 0.356129033        B 0.3603769 0.8429552
45: 0.225943145        B 0.7028077 0.3561290
46: 0.360376907        B 0.7159759 0.3603769
47: 0.169606203        B 0.3438164 0.9745535
48: 0.343816363        B 0.4396962 0.9745535
49: 0.067265545        B 0.9641856 0.3438164
50: 0.439696243        B 0.9641856 0.4396962
51: 0.024403516        B 0.3730828 0.9902976
52: 0.373082846        B 0.4713596 0.9902976
53: 0.290466668        B 0.9689225 0.3730828
54: 0.471359568        B 0.9689225 0.4713596
55: 0.402111615        B 0.4902595 0.8045104
56: 0.490259530        B 0.8801029 0.4902595
57: 0.477884140        B 0.4904800 0.6696598
58: 0.490480001        B 0.8396014 0.4904800
          Speed AnimalID    FSpeed    BSpeed
```

This shows all the clusters where either the following or previous four (+ the anchor cell) all have a max speed below our min speed (in this case 0.5)

In your code, just run `DT <- as.data.table(myDF)` where myDF is the name of the data.frame you are using.

For this analysis, we assume that GPS measurements are measured at constant intervals. I also am throwing out the first 4 and last 4 observations by setting `fill=1`. You should set `fill=` to your max speed.

Comment: @Splash1199 try `DT[!((FSpeed < 0.8 | BSpeed < 0.8) & date>as.Date("2015-05-15 21:30:00"))]`. This will return a `data.table` excluding (thats what the ! at the beginning does) all of the rows that meet the criteria.

Comment: if your GPS is not at constant times, then you need to rephrase your criteria (i.e not 5 events, but x seconds)

Comment: and finally, `date>as.Date("2015-05-15 21:30:00")` will exlude all times after that point in time (including the next day at say 8am.). You might want to switch that to be within a specific daily time range, something like `(hour(date) > 21.5 | hour(date) < 8)`

Comment: thanks for your answer! What do I do if my GPS data is not taken at constant time intervals? 

Also, do you know how I can incorporate the other components of my filter? I figured I could incorporate time my running something like 
`DT[FSpeed < 0.8 & date>as.POSIXct("2015-05-15 21:30:00")]`, but is there a way to delete the points after the first identified cluster?

I'm an R novice, so I'm finding this quite challenging.

Comment: actually, that `hour` returns an integer, so it wont work for 30 min intervals.... you'll need to use `as.ITime()`, and then `77400` (21:30 in seconds)

Comment: Hmm, okay. But I want to delete ALL points after the first identified cluster. Not just the ones that meet the condition [FSpeed < 0.8 & date>as.POSIXct("2015-05-15 21:30:00")]